# Group Theory abstract algebra

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a symmetry group of a circle. Show that G has elements of every finite order as well as elements of infinite order.

Comment: Can you describe a circle, then find a (nonidentity) map that takes that circle to itself?  Is that map an element of your group?

Comment: You can Rotate a circle.

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for guidelines. Figure out what's wrong with your question, and fix it.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** consider $\mathbb S^1 = \{e^{2\pi i t} \mid t \in [0,1]\} \subseteq \mathbb C$ and maps of the form $\mathbb S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb S^1, e^{2\pi i t} \mapsto e^{2\pi i t + \alpha}$, where $\alpha \in [0,1]$. What happens if $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$? What if $\alpha \in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$?